# Approximating the values in Sparse Matrix

Tags: c++, precision, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have a large sparse matrix of size N x N where N = 10^5, I have done certain calculations on it and filled some part of the matrix. I want to make the modification to element values in the below manner so that it looks better:

Example :
I have used prune method for replacing the values<0.00005 to zero:

```
A.prune(0.00005,0); //where A is of type Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
```

But this will lead to deletion of elements with value  -95,-2,-1, -98(basically all negatives will be gone).
Is there a better way through which I can approximate the values between 0 and 0.00005 to zero ? and values between 0 and -0.00005 to zero again.

**Note:**

I am doing this because with this the matrix ill become more sparse and calculations can be performed easily on it.

Comment: What is the question? Did `prune` not do what you expected?

Comment: @kazemakase     Yes it worked but for replacing values <0.00005 to zero, I want to approximate the rest of  values also. But prune "_Suppresses all nonzeros which are much smaller than reference under the tolerance epsilon_" what should I do for the rest? Like to make 0.99998 equal to one.

Comment: I don't know much about Eigen; just trying to help you get the question in a form so others can help you better :) What you want sounds like *rounding to a certain precision*. Maybe these search terms will get you further.

Comment: yes, first round the entries, then prune the true zeros, e.g., `A.coeffs() = (A.coeffs()*1e5).array().round()*1e-5);`followed by `A.prune()`.

Comment: @ggael   I don't want to remove the values such as -95,-8 etc  all i want is the values between -0.00005 and  +0.00005 be equal to zero so that it can be compressed easily later.Is there any better way of doing that(I have added it in the question now, my mistake!)

Comment: no, no !!! prune compares the magnitude of the coefficients, not their signed value. It would make no sense to neglect large negative values

Comment: @ggael          Thanks! I misinterpreted the definition given in documentation.